# Multiple CSS classes in an html element ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I know it is possible to have multiple CSS classes in an element, but I was wondering if it was possible to select which class to use by using a razor if statement?

So something like this (pseudo code)

```
<div @if( num items in Model ==0){
         class="Error";
       } else
        class ="home"; >
```

I would think that this would be possible, if anyone has some ideas I would appreciate their help!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<div class="@(Model.Count() == 0 ? "Error" : "home")">
```

But that looks ugly to me. I would probably write a custom HTML helper if I had to repeat this logic over my views.

Comment: Nice and clean in comparison to my long winded way.

Comment: Thanks @Darin, looks pretty clean to me as well.  It definitely got the job done for me.